How to migrate Databricks artifacts from one environment to another and change config paths at pipeline runtime?
We have a Azure Databricks workspace and Dev/QA/Prod environments. Everytime the Data engineers have to ship the artifacts from nonprod -> prod (e.g. Python notebooks, config modules, etc) they have to copy the artifacts manually over to the next environment and change the paths in the config files to work correctly in the new environment.
It's a hassle and they see an opportunity to reduce toil here by leveraging Azure Devops pipelines.
How do we create a pipeline around this to migrate these artifacts? What is the best practice? We've considered for example Azure Keyvault for storing variable specific environments and generalizing the config paths so that they are replaced dynamically during pipeline runtime. But is that really the best way? Is there a better way, maybe new method now to do this even easier? Things like that is what I'm trying to understand here to do it best way possible in 2024.
Here's a sample databricks workspace structure of the current setup as well as an example config file with hardcoded paths that always have to change for new environment config.
Databricks Workspace structure:


Workspace

->Shared
-->Demo
-->Metrics Engine
-->modules
--->_resources
--->test
--->example.ipynb
--->mod_config.ipynb
--->mod-schema.ipynb

mod_config.ipynb has some hardcoded paths for dev like this (they start with 'abfss'):
config = {

 ConfigurationKeys.ROOT_PATH  + Constants.FileFormats.CSV:                ConfigEntry(None, 'abfss://companyxyzanalyticsdev@companyxyzdatageneraldev.dfs.core.windows.net/source/companyxyz/extracts/sampledb'),

 ConfigurationKeys.ROOT_PATH  + Constants.FileFormats.PARQUET:                ConfigEntry(None, 'abfss://companyxyzanalyticsdev@companyxyzdatageneraldev.dfs.core.windows.net/sink/tables/parquet/'),

 ConfigurationKeys.OUTPUT_PATH:                                           ConfigEntry(None, 'abfss://companyxyzinternal@companyxyzdatageneraldev.dfs.core.windows.net/data-projects/internal/data-regression-analysis/resultset'),

 ConfigurationKeys.RELATIVE_PATH_DATALAKE_TABLES_TRANSACTIONS:            ConfigEntry(Constants.FileFormats.CSV, DataLake.RelativePaths.SourceTables.Transactions),

 ConfigurationKeys.RELATIVE_PATH_DATALAKE_TABLES_REGIONS:                 ConfigEntry(Constants.FileFormats.CSV, DataLake.RelativePaths.SourceTables.Regions),

 .............

So ideally at pipeline runtime, the paths would be changed to QA ones and Prod ultimately, because right now as you can see they're dev specific and normally they would have to be manually updated after copying them manually to other environments, which as mentioned is a hassle! So maybe if there's a transformation that would be possible to be done in the notebooks, or if the paths have to become generalized and the specific have to be stored in keyvault, etc. whatever the best approach would be.
FYI, the Databricks repo is hosted in bitbucket (though could be changed if necessary to Azure Repos and makes things easier, but Devs are very used to Bitbucket)
Also I have checked out this thread for example but it uses terraform to try update parameters. We don't use Terraform... however maybe if we have to resort to IaC after all, we can probably integrate Bicep if needed.
I also came across this repo example though it uses GitHub integration and we don't want to use GitHub. Also not sure if it's implemented with best practices for 2024.

Keyvault could be using scope, so example code: `DEFAULT_SCOPE_NAME = "examplekeyvault"
secretValue2 = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = DEFAULT_SCOPE_NAME, key = AZURE_KEY_VAULT_SECRET_KEY_NAME)
print(AZURE_KEY_VAULT_SECRET_KEY_NAME + " = " + secretValue2)
print(AZURE_KEY_VAULT_SECRET_KEY_NAME + " length = " + str(len(secretValue2)))`


How to migrate Databricks artifacts from one environment to another and change config paths at pipeline runtime?

I thinks you are on the correct direction. Before you deploy to databricks, you need to replace the config paths between different environment in the pipeline.
if you store the path value in keyvalut, link it in library variable group:

As you have hardcode paths in sample file mod_config.ipynb, you can use PowerShell script to replace the value.
The script below is search all strings between single quote and started with abfss, replace the value for 1st ,2nd, 3rd for the occurrence. You can add more if needed.
variables:
 - group: VG2

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $fileContent = Get-Content -Path modules/mod_config.ipynb
      echo $fileContent

      $pattern = "(?<=')abfss[^']*(?=')"
      $count = 0
      
      $fileContent | ForEach-Object {
          if ($_ -match $pattern) {
              $count++
              if ($count -eq 1) {
                  $_ -replace $pattern, "$(var1)"    # the variable from group
              } elseif ($count -eq 2) {
                  $_ -replace $pattern, "$(var2)"
              } elseif ($count -eq 3) {
                  $_ -replace $pattern, "$(var3)"
              } else {
                  $_
              }
          } else {
              $_
          }
      } | Set-Content -Path modules/mod_config.ipynb

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s'
    artifact: 'test'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'

I publish the artifact to check the file content, each value is replaced with different variable value correctly.

You can define different variable groups in different stages(environment), so that it will replace the value accordingly.
stages:
- stage: Dev           # first stage/environment
  variables:
    - group: VG2       # first variable group
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    pool: 
     name: wadepool
    steps:
    -  .....                  # the tasks to replace config paths and databricks deploy


- stage: Prod                 # 2nd stage/environment
  variables:
    - group: VG3              # 2nd variable group
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    pool: 
     name: wadepool
    steps:
       .....                    # the tasks to replace config paths and databricks deploy

Or you can use #{placeholder}# in the mod_config.ipynb(the placeholder name is same with variable name) , and use extension task replacetokens@6 to replace the value between different stages, it can also work.

stages:
- stage: Dev
  variables:
    - group: VG2
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    pool: 
     name: wadepool
    steps:
    - task: replacetokens@6
      inputs:
        sources: '**\mod_config.ipynb'

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s'
        artifact: 'test2'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
    ... your databricks tasks...
- stage: Prod
  variables:
    - group: VG3
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    pool: 
     name: wadepool
    steps:
    - task: replacetokens@6
      inputs:
        sources: '**\mod_config.ipynb'
    ... your databricks tasks


Thank you. Do you have this in a demo environment that I could look at working fully? I'm currently attempting to create a poc to demo before applying to actual project

I'm afraid there's no exact same pipeline you wanted. But you already have the pipeline with manual changed artifact, just implement the automate change in pipeline and deploy with same way.
